# How to dump `sklearn.neighbors.KDTree` object to hdf5?

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle, hdf5, kdtree

According to [document](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) of `sklearn.neighbors.KDTree`, we may dump `KDTree` object to disk with pickle.
However, it's very slow for both dumping and loading, and storage comsuming.

Is it possible to dump it to hdf5 format?

Answer (score 4):

You may make use of `__getstate__` and `__getstate__`. Most the internal quantities are in type array or scalar, thus suitable for hdf5. 
Still a bit more work to do, as the last term returned by `__getstate__` is a function, we may transalte it to string painlessly with `pickle.dumps` for hdf5 stroage.

If you find this is interesting, you may find the source code of `KDTree` [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi), and check the returned value by `__getstate__`.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import h5py
import pickle

"""
You may find the source code of KDTree from link below
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi
"""

__all__ = ["KDTreeH5"]


class KDTreeH5(KDTree):
    def dump(self, file):
        """
        file: str or HDF group
        """
        if not isinstance(file, h5py.Group):
            file = h5py.File(file)

        state = list(self.__getstate__())
        assert len(state) == 12
        # convert dist_metric to string for hdf5 storage.
        state[-1] = pickle.dumps(state[-1])
        for i, v in enumerate(state):
            file[str(i)] = v

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, file):
        """
        file: str or HDF group
        """
        if not isinstance(file, h5py.Group):
            file = h5py.File(file, 'r')

        state = [None] * 12
        for i in range(12):
            state[i] = file[str(i)].value
        # recover dist_metric from string.
        state[-1] = pickle.loads(state[-1])

        obj = cls.__new__(cls)
        obj.__setstate__(state)
        return obj
```

Comment: I found this trick very useful @Syrtis. Thanks for sharing!